# Regex - Last mention

Tags: regex

I'm using a Regex expression to extract mentions: `/\B@[a-z0-9_-]+/gi`.

For the following string "Hi @andrew my username is @dan and I like cakes.", it will return : `['@andrew', '@dan']`

What I would like is a Regex that get the last mention, with nothing after it:

"Hi @andrew my username is @dan and I like cakes." would return nothing

"Hi @andrew my username is @dan" would return `@dan`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end of line character '`$`' is probably what you're missing.

So try `/\B@[a-z0-9_-]+$/gi`

[Demo here](http://regex101.com/r/iX5xA8/1)